# Automator, AppleScript, Finder - The passing of the file name is strange

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I have the following problem. I want to write a service in Automator. It should pass a file to an AppleScript action. That works too. Strangely, the path exists twice.

Automator AppleScript Code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        set f to (input as text)
        set thisPOSIXPath to (the POSIX path of f)
        do script "/Applications/HandBrakeCLI --format av_mp4 --optimize --align-av --encoder x265 --quality 21 --vfr  --first-audio --mixdown stereo --ab 192 --first-subtitle -i "  & thisPOSIXPath & " -o /Desktop/FERTIG.m4v"
        return input
    end tell
end run
```

Terminal Output:

```
% /Applications/HandBrakeCLI --format av_mp4 --optimize --align-av --encoder x265 --quality 21 --vfr  --first-audio --mixdown stereo --ab 192 --first-subtitle -i /Users/testuser/Desktop/Sample Videos _ Dummy Videos For Demo Use.mp4Macintosh HD/Users/testuser/Desktop/Sample Videos _ Dummy Videos For Demo Use.mp4Macintosh HD/Users/testuser/Desktop/Sample Videos _ Dummy Videos For Demo Use.mp4 -o /Desktop/FERTIG.m4v
```

Where does it come from?

Comment: It sounds like you are getting items in addition to the service input - what are the actions before the AppleScript?

Comment: RE: "Strangely, the path exists twice.", well actually `Sample Videos _ Dummy Videos For Demo Use.mp4` appears **three** time after the `-i` _option_. Please include an appropriate screenshot of your **Automator** _workflow_ so we can see how it's set up. Otherwise, we are left to guess what you've done wrong.